# Specify depth* of key press event to OS - Java AWT Robot

Tags: java, awt, keystroke, awtrobot

I have a program, which by using the java Robot class, sends key strokes to the operating system.
I was wondering to what depth* of the OS does the class send the strokes?

For instance, are they sent to the lowest possible level (hardware), so the computer believes the key was physically pressed,  or are they sent to the highest possible level - to the applications with keyboard focus.
They mustn't be notably low level, since I've noticed that the key strokes aren't registered by Windows MouseKeys - they pass through as if MouseKeys were not active.

I can't find any specification of the depth; only "they are sent to the Operating System"

I was also wondering if it were possible to pass the intended depth of the keystroke in the OS to the robot class somehow?

I apologize if any of this is vague; I have little knowledge of how Key Events actually work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the inputs are sent to the OS, the OS redirects the input to the application in the foreground. You can switch between windows using JNA ([java sending keystrokes using robot class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771542/java-sending-keystrokes-using-robot-class)). Hopefully this help someone.