# java sending keystrokes using robot class

Tags: java, awt, keystore, awtrobot

I know it's possible to send keystrokes in java using Robot Class , but is there any way to specify the target process when it's already started ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Robot will send the keystrokes to whichever application window is on top. To send keystrokes to a specific target, you will want to set the target as the platform's foreground window first. Doing this may require native code such as that provided by JNI or (what I use) JNA. If you desire to send keystrokes to a background window, I believe that you cannot use Robot, that you will have to write native code. Of course all native code solutions will be platform dependent.

---

You ask:

> Would you please give me some more details on how to do it with JNA
>   sorry , I'm writing for windows

For Windows, you would interface with the user32.dll library. Something like this has worked for me:

User32.java

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.LONG_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

/**
 * JNA interface with Window's user32.dll
 * 
 * @author Pete S
 * 
 */
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

   interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
      boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg);
   }

   public static final int GW_OWNER = 4; // used with GetWindow to get win owner
   public static final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2; // used with GetNextWindow
   public static final int GA_ROOT = 2; // used with GetAncestor
   public static final int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20; // used with GetWindowLong
   public static final long WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000L;
   public static final Pointer HWND_TOP = new Pointer(0L); // used with
                                                           // SetWindowPos

   boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer userData);

   int GetWindowTextA(Pointer hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

   int SetForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetForegroundWindow();

   boolean GetWindowRect(Pointer hWnd, RECT rect);

   boolean SetWindowPos(Pointer hWnd, Pointer hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y,
         int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

   boolean MoveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, boolean bRepaint);

   boolean IsWindow(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetWindow(Pointer hWnd, int uCmd);

   LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, int nIndex);

   Pointer GetParent(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetAncestor(Pointer hWnd, int gaFlags);

   boolean IsWindowVisible(Pointer hWnd);
}
```

JnaUtil.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.LONG_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;

/**
 * static methods to allow Java to call Windows code. user32.dll code is as
 * specified in the JNA interface User32.java
 * 
 * @author Pete S
 * 
 */
public class JnaUtil {
   private static final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
   private static Pointer callBackHwnd;

   public static boolean windowExists(final String startOfWindowName) {
      return !user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

            if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.startsWith(startOfWindowName)) {
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
   }

   public static List<String> getAllWindowNames() {
      final List<String> windowNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {

         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();
            if (!wText.isEmpty()) {
               windowNames.add(wText);
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);

      return windowNames;
   }

   public static boolean windowExists(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.IsWindow(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getWinHwnd(final String startOfWindowName) {
      callBackHwnd = null;

      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

            if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.startsWith(startOfWindowName)) {
               callBackHwnd = hWnd;
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
      return callBackHwnd;
   }

   public static boolean setForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) != 0;
   }

   public static Pointer getForegroundWindow() {
      return user32.GetForegroundWindow();
   }

   public static String getForegroundWindowText() {
      Pointer hWnd = getForegroundWindow();
      int nMaxCount = 512;
      byte[] lpString = new byte[nMaxCount];
      int getWindowTextResult = user32
            .GetWindowTextA(hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount);
      if (getWindowTextResult == 0) {
         return "";
      }

      return Native.toString(lpString);
   }

   public static boolean isForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetForegroundWindow().equals(hWnd);
   }

   public static boolean setForegroundWindow(String startOfWindowName) {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(startOfWindowName);
      return user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) != 0;
   }

   public static Rectangle getWindowRect(Pointer hWnd) throws JnaUtilException {
      if (hWnd == null) {
         throw new JnaUtilException(
               "Failed to getWindowRect since Pointer hWnd is null");
      }
      Rectangle result = null;
      RECT rect = new RECT();
      boolean rectOK = user32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, rect);
      if (rectOK) {
         int x = rect.left;
         int y = rect.top;
         int width = rect.right - rect.left;
         int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
         result = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
      }

      return result;
   }

   /**
    * set window at x and y position with w and h width. Set on top of z-order
    * 
    * @param hWnd
    * @param x
    * @param y
    * @param w
    * @param h
    * @return boolean -- did it work?
    */
   public static boolean setWindowPos(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      int uFlags = 0;
      return user32.SetWindowPos(hWnd, User32.HWND_TOP, x, y, w, h, uFlags);
   }

   public static boolean moveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth,
         int nHeight) {
      boolean bRepaint = true;
      return user32.MoveWindow(hWnd, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, bRepaint );
   }

   public static Rectangle getWindowRect(String startOfWindowName)
         throws JnaUtilException {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(startOfWindowName);
      if (hWnd != null) {
         return getWindowRect(hWnd);
      } else {
         throw new JnaUtilException("Failed to getWindowRect for \""
               + startOfWindowName + "\"");
      }
   }

   public static Pointer getWindow(Pointer hWnd, int uCmd) {
      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, uCmd);
   }

   public static String getWindowText(Pointer hWnd) {
      int nMaxCount = 512;
      byte[] lpString = new byte[nMaxCount];
      int result = user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount);
      if (result == 0) {
         return "";
      }
      return Native.toString(lpString);
   }

   public static Pointer getOwnerWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, User32.GW_OWNER);
   }

   public static String getOwnerWindow(String childTitle) {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(childTitle);
      Pointer parentHWnd = getOwnerWindow(hWnd);
      if (parentHWnd == null) {
         return "";
      }
      return getWindowText(parentHWnd);

   }

   public static Pointer getNextWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      if (hWnd == null) {
         return null;
      }

      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, User32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
   }

   public static boolean isWindowVisible(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.IsWindowVisible(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getParent(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetParent(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getRoot(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetAncestor(hWnd, User32.GA_ROOT);
   }

   public static LONG_PTR getWindowLongPtr(Pointer hWndP, int nIndex) {
      HWND hwnd = new HWND(hWndP);
      return user32.GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, nIndex);
   }

   // main method to test the library
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      List<String> winNameList = getAllWindowNames();
      for (String winName : winNameList) {
         System.out.println(winName);
      }

      String[] testStrs = { "Untitled-Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad",
            "Untitled  -  Notepad", "Java-Epic", "Java - Epic", "Fubars rule!",
            "The First Night", "New Tab", "Citrix X", "EHR PROD - SVC" };
      for (String testStr : testStrs) {
         Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(testStr);
         boolean isWindow = windowExists(hWnd);
         System.out.printf("%-22s %5b %16s %b%n", testStr,
               windowExists(testStr), hWnd, isWindow);
      }

      String notePad = "Untitled - Notepad";
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(notePad);
      System.out
            .println("is it foreground window? " + isForegroundWindow(hWnd));
      boolean foo = setForegroundWindow(notePad);
      System.out.println("foregroundwindow: " + foo);
      Thread.sleep(400);
      System.out
            .println("is it foreground window? " + isForegroundWindow(hWnd));
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("here A");
      try {
         Rectangle rect = getWindowRect(notePad);
         System.out.println("rect: " + rect);
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         System.out.println("here B");

         BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
         System.out.println("here C, img is " + img);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         System.out.println("here D. icon is null? " + icon);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
         System.out.println("here E. label is null? " + label);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               System.out.println("here F");               
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
               System.out.println("here G");
            }
         });

      } catch (AWTException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JnaUtilException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

JnaUtilException.java

```
public class JnaUtilException extends Exception {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public JnaUtilException(String text) {
      super(text);
   }

}
```

Comment: Would you please give me some more details on how to do it with JNA

Comment: @BasilMostafa: again if you use JNA or JNI, then your solution will be platform dependent. What platform are you writing this for? Windows?

Comment: sorry , I'm writing for windows

Comment: @BasilMostafa: above is some code that I've used for this purpose.

Comment: This is very useful to me, thanks. One question about it: Can anybody tell me the difference between SetWindowPos and MoveWindow? Just curious!

Comment: @BrianOCarroll: have you checked out the msdn entry for these functions? That would be where I would always start.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. It seems MoveWindow is better suited to child windows (position is relative to parent window). SetWindowPos is probably what I'm looking for (absolute screen co-ordinates)